# unable to display latin characters using java

Tags: java, utf-8

i'm using the following lines of code to read the data frm db

```
ob = new String(loadBlob.toByteArray());
ob = Util.decrypt(Constants.ENCRYPTION_KEY, ob);
ob = new String(Base64.decodeBase64(ob.getBytes("UTF-8")), "UTF-8");
```

but while displaying the latin characters appears as a box. even in db proper characters are available.

Comment: Error is likely on the first line, are you really sure the BLOB is encoded with your JVM's default encoding?

Comment: Shouldn't you decode 64 before decrypting ?